# How can I set the 'Enable Enhanced Instruction Set' in msbuild?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

How can I set the value of the param '`Enable Enhanced Instruction Set`' when compiling with `msbuild` from command line ?

[image]

Comment: presumably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task will work

Comment: What is your VS version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448256/how-can-msbuild-exe-be-set-up-to-embed-the-proper-value-for-sse2-into-m-ix86-fp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To** realize this, it might be a complex but can be done. You only need to be with the help of a MSBuild property to transmit the value from msbuild command line into the `EnableEnhancedInstructionSet` [Item matadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#item-metadata).

MSBuild can transmit the msbuild property rather then item metadata.

**Solution**

Modify these on your xxx.vcxproj file:

**1) First** set a default value `Not Set` for it.

```
<PropertyGroup>

<Instruction_Set>NotSet</Instruction_Set>

</PropertyGroup>


<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>$(Instruction_Set)</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

**2) Then**, you can use msbuild command line like these to set it:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.vcxproj -t:build -p:Instruction_Set=StreamingSIMDExtensions
```

The values of the parameters are these:

**The latter is what you need to use**

**SSE**: StreamingSIMDExtensions

**SSE2**: StreamingSIMDExtensions2

**AVX**: AdvancedVectorExtensions

**AVX2**: AdvancedVectorExtensions2

**AVX512**: AdvancedVectorExtensions512

**IA32**: NoExtensions

**Not Set**: NotSet

You should use the value of it on the command line:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.vcxproj -t:build -p:Instruction_Set=xxx
```

===========================================

**Update**

I tested all the parameters under **VS2019** successfully. And I wonder where goes wrong.

Please see these:

**a)** use **SSE**:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.vcxproj -t:build -p:Instruction_Set=StreamingSIMDExtensions
```

[image]

**b)** use **AVX**:

```
 msbuild xxx\xxx.vcxproj -t:build -p:Instruction_Set=AdvancedVectorExtensions
```

[image]

**c)** use **AVX512**:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.vcxproj -t:build -p:Instruction_Set=AdvancedVectorExtensions512
```

[image]

**d)** use **IA32**:

```
 msbuild xxx\xxx.vcxproj -t:build -p:Instruction_Set=NoExtensions
```

[image]

Comment: It works! but just one comment.
Almost in the version of VS I'm running (2019) the values of the parameter are wrong.
It accept values such as 'NotSet','AdvancedVectorExtensions2','StreamingSIMDExtensions2' etc..

Comment: All values which I list are all tested in VS2019 and I make sure that they are all right. So I am curious where it goes wrong. You should use `-p:Instruction_Set=StreamingSIMDExtensions` or `-p:Instruction_Set=StreamingSIMDExtensions2` ....etc.

Comment: The parameters I list are followed by the actual values to be entered. I have update my answer. See `update` and you can check it.

Comment: OK sorry, I misunderstood the way the params were written ;). At first I thought the bold text was the value of the param

Comment: It does not matter. Anyway, your issue has resolved by our joint efforts. I have added it into the answer. Have a nice day!